# Static Website Indexing Issue

Tags: php, indexing, title

I have a static website written on PHP. As a beginner i am very keen to know about two things.
- How to index the search results in search engines. This website will fetch some results from my another site, by the way....
As i have said that it is a static php based website and it has only some pages...
Its search page url is something like this:
 `www.mysite.com/results.php?q=free+antivirus+download`
- And my another question is how to change search result page Title with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the webmaster tools from google. You can add your site there, and see how google indexex your site.

There are also some tips on how to make your site more SEO friendlier like a sitemap.xml or a robots.txt

Each page on your site must have a unique url for google to index the page. The example you give is not very SEO friendly.